# simple problem of calculus.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, optimization

A company wishes to manufacture a box with a volume of $36ft^3$ that is open on top and twice as long as it is wide.Find the dimensions of the box produced from the minimum amount of material.

My attempt:I suppose that $x$ is the width of box then the length of the box will be $2x$

So $V=2x
\cdot x\cdot h=2x^2h=36$

So $h=\frac{18}{x^2}$

Further what to do?I do not know.Infact I do not understand the meaning of "Find the dimensions of the box produced from the minimum amount of material."

Answer (score 0):

The amount of material used is the surface of the box. The surface should be $S=2x^2+6xh$ (why?) Substitute $h$ and find the minimum of the equation.

Comment: h and x are both unknown.

Comment: yes but you can express $h$ in terms of $x$. If you substitute $h=\frac{18}{x^2}$ in $S(x,h)=2x^2+6xh$ you get $S(x)=2x^2+\frac{108}{x}$ which you should be able to determine the minimum from.

Comment: Yes I have found $x=-3$ is the minima for $S(x)$.Thanks dear.

Comment: hold on. From a reality point of view, does $x=-3$ seem plausible?

Comment: But it produces minima $x=3$

Comment: Oh sorry it is $x=3$.Thanks